# Task Parallel Library and Windows Service

Tags: multithreading, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I have the following requirement.

An asp.net website, and based on logged in user request it will start one windows service on background(run the windows service from code). Even though the user log out from the site, the service will continues to run.

Simultaneously any number of logged in user can run the service (the code inside service is updating database based on the logged in user id). So to achieve this I used the TPL (Task Parallel Library) and in my windows service “OnCustomCommand” event, I am creating the task. That means if 10 user calls the service, 10 task will be crated.

Please note I have used TPL “TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning peoperty” as the task is long running. I know if we set this it will create a new thread. So I don’t want if 100 logged in user use 100 threads when they call the service. So I am restricting the number of new threads to create.

But I need to know whether I am in right path? Is this the best approach?

Following is the windows service code and the approach I used. [Please note its not the exact code, this is the approach I am going to implement]

```
protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
        {
            if (command == 1)
            {
                if (threadCount < 10) // here I will check the already created threads count, 
                                      // if it is less than 10, then only will create a new task and there by new thread. 
                                      // Otherwise the request will be in queue and when one task is done it will reduce the threadcount.
                {
                    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        ThreadProcedure();
                    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
                }

            }
        }

        private void ThreadProcedure()
        {
            threadCount++; //will update the thread count and save 
            // my service logic 
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: why use long running then?

Comment: @Dev Do you only access the database and update it inside your thread? or is the thread also used to invoke the windows service?

Comment: @ I3arnon -- > the code inside windows service will take 10-12 hours to complete. The user cant log in site that much time. That's why i have used the windows service concept to do the task in background.

Comment: @ Yuval --> Its not only accessing the DB and updating it..there is some complex logic and that makes the service to run for long time. Its actually extracting data from another big database..Thread is not used to invoke the windows service. Thread in used inside windows service to do the long running task. I used the concept threading because the request is coming from multiple users. So for each request one thread will handle it. Even though I am restricting the number of threads to be created simultaneously.